# How can I make a crosstab based on a subreport in BIRT?

Tags: birt, subreport, crosstab

I created a report with subreports like in the following tutorial: http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.birt.doc/birt/subreport.13.2.html

But instead to put the subreport in a table element, I want to use a crosstab.
So I added a datacube and crosstab based on the dataset from the subreport.

The data in the crosstab allways shows the data from the "default value".
And when I remove the default value the crosstab is empty.

I use BIRT version 2.5.2.

How can I make this work?

Comment: can you clarify your question? It sounds as though your subreport is selecting data based on the value passed to it, and you are surprised that the data reported in the crosstab in the subreport is only for the value passed to the subreport. If you can include some examples of what you are trying to do, and what you are actually seeing, this should clarify your requirements.

Comment: @Mark, well to clarify it I added the following line to my question: "But instead to put the subreport in a table element, I want to use a crosstab." Hope that clarifies it!

Comment: I think I can understand what you are trying to do - run a subreport from within each cell of a crosstab - but not why you are trying to do it.

Comment: @Mark, sorry, but I think I still was not clear enough... I want to have a crosstab in the detail line of the master report, but opposed to a table-element you can not specify a Data Set Parameter binding.

Answer (score 2):

When you add the crosstab to the report, do not bind it to the data set directly.  Instead, on the data binding area of the crosstab properties set it to "Inherit from Container".  This will give you the filtered view of the data you want for your crosstab.

Comment: I do not see the option "Inherit from Container" in my version of BIRT (2.5.2). Should I find it on the "Binding" tab of the crosstab? The only options I see are 'None' or my data cube.

Answer (score -1):

I just did it using the crosstab filters

Comment: This is quite unclear. Consider adding examples and explanations.